# how can I return a result from a function into a variable?

Tags: swift, function, variables

I have a variable :

```
var name = [Nick,John,Peter]
```

and a function:

```
 func name(){

 var personname = []
         .......

       return personname
 }
```

the result of the function are the names of the people Nick,John,Peter. How can I return the result into the variable.I mean I do not want to write the names manually I want to populate them from the function, because the function display all of the names. I am beginner and I will be glad if you show me the right syntaxis.

```
  var name = [????] = [personname()] or how????
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Swift Language Guide - Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html); passing over the chapter will help you not only with this specific question, but mainly with grasping the essential basics of Swift functions.

Comment: I don't understand. What should the invocation of `name()` return?

Comment: the personname in this case are the names [Nick,John,Peter], but in stead of writing var name = [Nick,John,Peter], I want to write var name = personname. What is the correct syntaxis I cannot find it in the file

Comment: var name = personname. is that right??

Comment: @MercedesFanPage you REALLY need to do some research. I'd recommend the Swift Language Guide, which you can get for free in iBooks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `->` to return something from a function. Here is an example:

```
static let people = ["Nick", "John", "Peter"]

func getPerson(index: Int) -> String
{
    return self.people[index] //index is number of a person, 0 will be the first one, 1 is second, etc.
}

func showTeam()
{
    // some code

    print("This is a first boy: \(self.getPerson[0])")

    // some code
}
```